# Referencing another model type within a model (Foreign key error)

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am trying to add a model type into a model class to represent an interaction of, who owns a particular item. Here a company will be associated to a project they're working on. When running Add-migration migName which works out fine, I would then do update-database and it gives me the following error:

```
Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE [Companies] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Project_WorkingOnProjectProjectId] FOREIGN KEY ([WorkingOnProjectProjectId]) REFERENCES [Project] ([ProjectId]) ON DELETE NO ACTION;

Foreign key 'FK_Companies_Project_WorkingOnProjectProjectId' references invalid table 'Project'.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors
```

The second error makes sense since the Projects  table does not get created for some reason, I assume it's because the error occurs which then stops the whole operation.
Would anyone be able to give an insight as to what is causing this issue?

### Company Model

```
    public class Company
{
    [Key]
    public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }

    public Project WorkingOnProject { get; set; }
}
```

### Projects Model

```
    public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

They're both present in my ApplicationDbContext class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : ApiAuthorizationDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(
        DbContextOptions options,
        IOptions<OperationalStoreOptions> operationalStoreOptions) : base(options, operationalStoreOptions)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> UserAccountInfo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: _"the Projects table does not get created for some reason"_ - did you manually remove migrations?

Comment: I did remove the original few that were created, I have since stopped. Don't think deleting them was good although I can "Restore" them from the recycle bin. However, during those migrations, the projects table did not create. If I restore the previous migrations now I just get a build failed error when doing update-database

Comment: You should not manually remove migrations, the snapshot keeps metadata about the current state of the models. Delete all migrations and start anew, or prepare for a lot of manual labor.

Comment: After deleting all and doing Add-Migration InitialMigration I have received the following error: "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database"

Comment: Yes, you have to keep your database and migrations in sync. Either drop and recreate your database, or make sure the applied migrations actually match your database. Alternatively, rename existing tables, run the migrations, transport your data and then delete the old, renamed tables.